# Can anyone tell me what is wrong here in this loop?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

```
 #vl = [40.08, 36.6, 41.0, 35.2, 41.0]  
indices = []                 
for x in vl:
    if x == max(vl):
        indices.append(vl.index(x))
print(indices)
```

**Here max element 41 is present 2 times in the list at indexes 2 and 4. So, these indexes should be appended to the list indices. I am getting the output as [2,2] instead of [2,4]. Can Anyone please tell me what is wrong with this code? **

Comment: `.index` also returns the first index of the value in the list. Since the values are equal, the same index is returned twice.

Comment: @MegaIng Thank you! Please tell me which method I can use here to get the output I am looking for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: for x in range(len(vl)):
                        if vl[x] == max(vl):
                            indices.append(x)
                    print(indices)

Comment:  The above code worked for me

Comment: Check out `enumerate(vl)`

Answer (score 0):

You get `[2, 2]` as `index()` is going to always give you the index of the first match.

I think you want to check out `enumerate()` here as it will give you the indices you are looking for in addition to the values.

**Via List Comprehension:**

```
vl = [40.08, 36.6, 41.0, 35.2, 41.0]
indices = [index for index, value in enumerate(vl) if value == max(vl)]
print(indices)
```

**Via Traditional Loop:**

```
vl = [40.08, 36.6, 41.0, 35.2, 41.0]
indices = []
for index, value in enumerate(vl):
    if value == max(vl):
        indices.append(index)
print(indices)
```

both should give you:

```
[2, 4]
```